# Merge tags 1099 and form-1099

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we merge tags [1099](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1099) and [form-1099](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099) as they are same.

The tag [form-1099](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099) can be primary as we have all forms starting with form-. The tag [1099](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1099) can be made a synonym.

If possible we should also have a tag wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merged! Still need to create the Wiki. (anyone?)

Comment: What does it mean to create a wiki? Does that mean selecting a quintessential question, or perhaps creating a general post about the wiki topic?

Comment: A tag wiki is just a canonical definition of what we mean by that tag.

Comment: The tag wiki is in place now

Comment: Yes, it was in the review queue earlier today, and I approved. Glad someone authored it.